# how to start an Activity behind the current one?

Tags: android, android-activity

In my app, In an special situation I need to start an Activity and put it behind the current showing Activity, I mean if the current Activity, which is being shown by the user was closed, the user now can see the Activity which I just started. how to do that?

Comment: onBackPressed start that activity

Comment: the current Activity is not handled by my app, it is an Activity of Android System

Comment: inside onActivityResult() start that activity.

Comment: +1 for your beautiful mind! sorry, I had to mention more details in my Q. actually the first Activity is the Activity that starts while the phone is ringing, so I haven't started that and I cant ask for its result

Comment: could you possibly start the background activity and just bring up the current activity again after that?

Comment: nice! but actually the first Activity is the Activity that starts while the phone is ringing, so I haven't started that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this.

Activities will always start right away. You cannot manipulate the back stack in the way you want.

You would have to detect the activity closing and then start your new activity then.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your case by using `onDestroy ()`

Perform any final cleanup before an activity is destroyed. This can happen either because the activity is finishing (someone called finish() on it, or because the system is temporarily destroying this instance of the activity to save space. You can distinguish between these two scenarios with the isFinishing() method.

Note: do not count on this method being called as a place for saving data! For example, if an activity is editing data in a content provider, those edits should be committed in either onPause() or onSaveInstanceState(Bundle), not here. This method is usually implemented to free resources like threads that are associated with an activity, so that a destroyed activity does not leave such things around while the rest of its application is still running. There are situations where the system will simply kill the activity's hosting process without calling this method (or any others) in it, so it should not be used to do things that are intended to remain around after the process goes away.

Derived classes must call through to the super class's implementation of this method. If they do not, an exception will be thrown.

Source : [http://developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29)

Comment: I think you mean I start the second Activity in `onDestroy()` method of first one. not a solution in my case as the first Activity in not of my app